# Clip a PCB against a 3 mm plastic protection

Tags: pcb, mount

Is there a way to clip the PCB against the 3mm plastic protection surface? The image is below.
I need that it stays in the position shown in the image, with the connectors side sticking out.
That PCB is just for the example, it will be a new PCB so I can change its form or placement to solder some kind of clip to the PCB that would just clip into the 3mm plastic protection.

[image]

Comment: While I question Why you would not screw the PCB to the plastic (that screw already seems to be causing clearance issues if you need that much clearance) you can likely do it with a 3mm metal spacer and some metal to sandwidth to the plastic.

Comment: I'm still studying the fastest way to assemble this, one possibility is to use the visible screw on one side and clip on the other. I wanted to avoid making holes on the plastic protection, which will take longer because I have to remove all screws, take it out, measure and make the holes, put everything together.

Comment: Use double sided tape is bodgy but quick.

Comment: If your OK with bodging, then using a blank PCB as a template, drill short holes e.g. 3.6mm (set the drill bit only pcb width + 2mm out of the drill), drill holes slightly smaller than your screws and fit 2 very short wood screws into the platic to secure your actual PCB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Google search: Double-sided tape PCB pillars
```

You can get these in various sizes to suit different heights and different holes: -

[image]

They have double sided tape on the bottom so they just fix in place and you should be good to go. Here's a different type: -

[image]

And a range of heights: -

[image]

You can even get them that work with a screw too: -

[image]

There are plenty of options and quite a few suppliers: -

[image]

Comment: This looks nice, are there the same that clip from the side of the 3mm plastic instead of the sticker?

Comment: You asked for this: *Is there a way to clip the PCB against the 3mm plastic protection surface?* I can't answer your comment question because I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Not to scale but something like this: https://photos.app.goo.gl/jZHBTbDWiDoAE9ux6 where the 3mm plastic protection would go inside the slot (on the side), so no need to use sticker.

Comment: I've never seen one but I guess you could easily make one from the basic pillar above.